# permanently delete every file in git not referenced by HEAD

Tags: git

I have an old git repo with a ton of cruft. I'd like to permanently delete every file in the history that isn't referenced by HEAD to free up space on the server. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git clean -d -x -f` removes all untracked files and directories and ignored ones. If you want to test it without affecting the repository change `-f` with `-n` to run the command in dry-run mode.

If you want to clean instead all tracked files, in my opinion is better to copy youw project in a new folder (with all ignored/untracked files removed) and start a new repository, mantaining the old one as backup for some time.

Comment: thank you, unless someone else chimes in with a simple solution that'll probably be the solution

Comment: git-clean is about removing untracked files from the working tree.  Was I wrong in thinking that the question was also about removing anything in old commits (on other branches) that is not reachable from HEAD?  If so, I would think that there's some strategy where you get rid of any references to anything other than the HEAD commit, and then use git-gc to clean it all up, but I've never used git-gc myself so won't propose a solution...

Comment: if you want to remove files from history, search around here `git-filter-branch` command. But if one changes history of a remote repository must handle problem with other users that have a local copy of repository itself. In order to avoid these problem I prefer to re-create the clean repository, because even by using `git-filter-branch` users should re-clone the updated repository.

Comment: You can't remove files from history if they are part of a commit in any branch you want to keep alive. Every commit in git refers to its parent, all the way back to the beginning, and you can't modify the commit to extract a file or all of your hashes (commit IDs) don't work, because the content of the commit is a part of what makes up the hash. You are really better off starting over, if this is what you are after.

Comment: I ended up doing something like `cat ~/files_to_del.txt | xargs --replace=name git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm name' master` where `files_to_del.txt` was the list of large binary blobs I wanted to permanently nuke